# Filter Year on Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I filter a Year on Oracle SQL Developer?

I need to filter a table from a specific year. For example: all data from 2020.

I tried use this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    YEAR(date_column) = 2020
```

But I don't know what the correct query is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the oracle docs for working with dates. Here is a common method which works for many DBMS, including Oracle.

```
where extract(year from date_column) = '2020'
```